# If the below given relation between two matrices is true, then calculate the value of $2a + 10b$

Tags: matrices

I am not from maths background but I want to solve this problem.
$$   
  2  \begin{bmatrix}
    a-2 & 2b  \\
    4 & -8  \\         
    \end{bmatrix}
 =    \begin{bmatrix}
        a+4 & b+3  \\
        8 & a-6b  \\         
        \end{bmatrix}  $$

Comment: You can equate the elements of the two matrices as they are both $2\times 2$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! To multiply a matrix by a number, you just have to multiply each coefficient of the matrix by this number, and to identify two matrices you identify them coefficient by coefficient. Thus it is equivalent to system of 4 equations with 2 unknowns, which may or may not have solutions.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the description?

Answer (score 2):

Formally,

$$   
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d  \\         
    \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
        e & f  \\
        g & h  \\         
        \end{bmatrix}  $$
if and only if $$ a=e, \\b=f, \\c=g, \\d=h$$

So two matrices are the same if and only if their respective entries are equivalent.

Another property you need is that
$$ \mu  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d  \\         
    \end{bmatrix}
=  \begin{bmatrix}
    \mu a & \mu b  \\
    \mu  c & \mu d  \\         
    \end{bmatrix}$$

For any coefficient $\mu$.

I hope this helps you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

$  \begin{bmatrix}
    2a-4 & 4b  \\
    8 & -16  \\         
    \end{bmatrix}
 =    \begin{bmatrix}
        a+4 & b+3  \\
        8 & a-6b  \\         
        \end{bmatrix}$

leads to the system

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 2 a-4=a+4 \\
 4 b=b+3 \\
 -16=a-6 b \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Which can be written as

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a=8 \\
 b=1 \\
 -16=8-6  \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

The system is incompatible thus there is no solution

Hope this helps

Comment: $a=8$ small error! Although this shouldn't affect the final result

Answer (score 0):

$2a-4 = a+4 \implies a=8$

$4b = b+3 \implies b=1$

Therefore,

2$a+10b = 16+10
       = 26$